# How to "automatically" copy files from source to deployment helm folder

Tags: kubernetes-helm, configmap

I have the following files in my source folder

```
deployment/
    openshift/
        templates/
            (helm deployment files, like deployment.yaml, configmap.yaml, ...)
    values.test.yaml
    application.yaml

resources/
    application.yaml
```

In order to add the application.yaml I manually copied the file to the deployment/openshift folder. Is it possible to somehow define in the values.test.yaml the "original" route to the file so then I don't need to copy the application.yaml file to the openshift folder.

Comment: How does it get used?  Is a symlink enough?  If this is part of a Spring application, can it just be compiled into your jar file?

Comment: Hi David, it's not a spring application